# what will be the xpath for an image

Tags: selenium, xpath

This is the html code:

```
<img id="gwt-uid-260" class="gwt-Image" src="pmm/files/_sisterhood_of_motherhood.jpg-16cdb703-2696-4bf5-a5d0-9813e370a291_thumbnail/image.png" style="visibility: visible; width: 253px; height: 140.837px;"/>
```

I want to know how to write the xpath for the image

Comment: `//img[@id="gwt-uid-260"]/@src`

Comment: Have you made any attempt, possibly starting from [answer given](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31869506/2998271) in your previous question, to accomplish this task?

Comment: but i dont want to give id as it will be dynamic...how do i give xpath without id ? and how should i identify the first image?

Comment: There you go, there are many ways to write the xpath and you know better about the most suitable selector. Decide how you want to select the element (probably in simple English), then try to translate it into XPath and we will be happy to help if you have problem with that process

Answer (score 0):

You can get the first image on the page with the following XPath:

```
//img[1]
```

Comment: This is the absolute xpath: html/body/div[3]/div[3]/div/div[3]/div/div[3]/div/div[3]/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[6]/div/div[5]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div/table/tbody/tr/td

Answer (score 0):

Use below xpath if Src image is not going to change:-

```
//img[starts-with(@id,'gwt-uid') and contains(@src,'sisterhood_of_motherhood.jpg')]
```

Comment: Dynamic need some input that is unique. Even when you need it dynamic, you need to pass some input to get hold of it. Like image name, etc. With the help of this input you will construct your dynamic xpath. How script will understand which image you want. So, you have to provide that is unique to image. What input you have?

Comment: I want it to be dynamic and i am getting an error - Element locator 'xpath=//img[starts-with(@id,'gwt-uid') and contains(@src,'sisterhood_of_motherhood.jpg')]' did not match any elements.

Comment: I inserted your html markup in one of the other webpages and tried to inspect with above mentioned xpath, its working fine.

Comment: it gives me this error:                                                                           ValueError: Element locator 'xpath=//img[starts-with(@id,'gwt-uid') and contains(@src,'sisterhood_of_motherhood.jpg')]' did not match any elements.

Comment: //img[@class='gwt-Image' and contains(@id,'gwt-uid')]    try this